# Add hyperlink to paragraph using word Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm trying to add an hyperlink to some XML being **inserted in a field** of a Word Document (using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word).

The XML being inserted contains multiple paragraphs, each containing some text that should be converted to a hyperlink. The text that contains the hyperlink is extracted from the end of the paragraph after the "Available at " substring is found.

The following code is able to create the hyperlink but the first hyperlink is always applied to all paragraphs. I was expecting the code to create an hyperlink for each of the paragraphs being iterated.

My guess is that the paragraph.Range object is pointing to text that is in fact the whole XML inserted as opposed to the text contained within the paragraph. I've also confirmed that the `paragraph.Range.Text` property returns the correct text for each paragraph so I am completely confused as to what should be expected for the Range property.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bibliography))
{
    const string linkToken = "Available at ";

    field.Result.InsertXML(bibliography);

    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in field.Result.Paragraphs)
    {   
        var paragraphText = paragraph.Range.Text;

        var indexOfLink = paragraphText.IndexOf(linkToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        if (indexOfLink >= 0)
        {
            var linkStart = indexOfLink + linkToken.Length;
            var linkPart = paragraphText.Substring(linkStart);

            Uri uriFound;

            if (Uri.TryCreate(linkPart, UriKind.Absolute, out uriFound))
            {
                object linkAddress = uriFound.ToString();

                paragraph.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(paragraph.Range, ref linkAddress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```